# Wordpress Responsive Header issues

Tags: wordpress, header, responsive-design, media-queries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wordpress Responsive Navbar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045726/wordpress-responsive-navbar-problems)

Im trying to create a header for my wordpress theme that is responsive here: http://22twenty.com/wordpress/

as you can see they are grouped in a "square"
and if you resize the page down and back up it really meses up: when its small a white box appear and when you scale it back up the nav is all over the place.

css is here: http://22twenty.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Wallspacecopy/style.css

it is a wordpress theme as i said so if you need any more files to help out just ask.

### So what i'm asking is there something that has to be added to it or changed to make a already working header(used on another site) work on a wordpress theme and if not what all do you believe is wrong with it.

Thanks

Denver

Comment: First of all you're getting a 404 on your http://22twenty.com/wordpress/js/modernizr-2.5.2.min.js, you should fix that up.

Comment: The page is taking forever to load for me at the moment, each of your 15 or so images are between 1-2MB. Also you're setting the li {display:inline;} when maybe look at ul li {float:left; width: 48%;} instead.

Comment: Yea i have to crop the images im not sure i understand the ul li {float:left; width: 48%;} and i will fix the js

Comment: ok so i fixed the 404 error, but the nav is still messed up

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS from

```
header ul li{
  z-index:30000;
    display: inline; /* you are changing this line */
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

to

```
header ul li{
  z-index:30000;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Also you should get rid of the empty  tag that contains the  (see http://jsbin.com/agiwev/1/ for an example)

Comment: Do you know how i would get the it to get out of the box and in a line?

Comment: They are in a "box" because they are stacking themselves within the space provided.  The get them in a "line" you simply extend the space the list can occupy.